# GWT ListBox setVisibleItemCount and IE 11

Tags: gwt, listbox, internet-explorer-11

I have a GWT (2.5.1) ListBox that I want to show fully open, displaying all items. I accomplish this by calling 'setVisibleItemCount(myListbox.getItemCount());'.  I can then select any item in the list box.  This works in the latest versions of Chrome, Firefox, Safari and IE versions prior to 11 on Windows 7 SP1. It even works in IE 11 on Windows 8.1.

The issue seems to be only with IE 11 on Windows 7. I have both onKeyUp and onChange event handlers.  The latter never gets called when I try to select an item.  In fact, I cannot select an item in the list. It behaves as if the list box were disabled but it isn't.  I can trigger an onKeyUp event successfully and then all works fine from that point on.  If I double click in the list box, the entire list appears to get selected.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I’ve also tried GWT 2.60 RC1 but that didn’t help.

Comment: GWT 2.6.0 didn't help either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue with List Boxes in IE11 (on windows 8) - it seemed as if the List Boxes where disabled, no reaction on clicking. In my case it happened after a row in a Cell Table was selected.

I tested in IE developer console (F12) with a different document mode, and this is strange, but true, and everything worked fine when I changed it to "8". So I added the following meta-tag to my gwt-html-page:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

Hope that helps.